# Profile page was not updated after I connected to new Facebook account

Tags: bug, profile-picture

Three years ago, I connected my old facebook account with my account on SO. I changed my profile picture on SO to be the same as my Facebook profile picture(My SO profile picture changes whenever I change the FB account profile picture because it loads this link `https://graph.facebook.com/{profile-id}/picture?type=large`).

A year later, I deleted my old Facebook account and created a new one.  I removed the old FB account from my SO account and connected the newly created facebook account.

Now whenever I set my SO profile picture to be as the same as my Facebook account, I see a blank broken image. I guess that's because the link to my facebook profile image was not updated after I changed the connected facebook account.

The bug is that when I change the profile picture to be the same as facebook profile picture, I get a blank/broken image. That's because the link that fetches my profile image from facebook points always to my old deleted Facebook account `https://graph.facebook.com/{my-old-profile-id}/picture?type=large`.